# Lookup headers and selectively sum cells below it

Tags: excel-formula, match, sumifs

I am trying to find a specific column based on month (B1) and sum the cells under it. Furthermore, im trying to only sum the cells in that column by the designated region (D1). This is what I figured it would be but excel doesn't see it as a valid function.

```
=SUMIFS(ADDRESS(MATCH(A3,A:A,0)+10,MATCH(B1,3:3,0)):ADDRESS(MATCH(A3,A:A,0)+1,MATCH(B1,3:3,0)),A4:A$12,D1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=SUMIFS(INDEX($1:$1048576,0,MATCH(B1,3:3,0)),A:A,D1)
```

The `INDEX($1:$1048576,0,MATCH(B1,3:3,0))` returns the whole column where Row 3 equals B1.  Then sums that column where column A equals D1.

If you want to limit it to only Rows 4:12 like your current formula:

```
=SUMIFS(INDEX($4:$12,0,MATCH(B1,3:3,0)),$A$4:$A$12,D1)
```

Comment: Perfect. Can I do the same thing but only sum visible cells (non-hidden)?

Comment: That is another whole question.  google `Subtotal with Conditions Excel`

Comment: Instead of 1 and 0 I am using X and Blank for the cells. To do the same thing I am using the following formula but it is coming back as #VALUE!. =SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(3,INDEX($1:$1048576,0,MATCH($B$1,$3:$3,0))),--(($A:$A=D$1))). What am I doing wrong with the formula.

Comment: @ABBO ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

The following will sum based on Month, Region, and Manager...

```
=SUMIFS(INDEX($D$4:$J$12,0,MATCH(B1,$D$3:$J$3,0)),$A$4:$A$12,D1,$B$4:$B$12,F1)
```

Hope this helps!